# How to make a good invite from contacts feature

Tags: facebook, mobile, contacts, api-design

I'm designing a mobile application which communicates with an API and I was wondering something.

My app is kind of a social network on which you can have friends and stuff like this. I wanted to add a feature to access phone contacts and see who is not subscribed on the app to invite him, and also ask to access to Facebook's friend list of the user and do the same thing.

I also want to check if a person in your phone's contacts is registered in the application to send him a friend request.

But the way i see it seems pretty heavy, i mean sending your whole phone contact list through the internet so the API can check every phone number and email adress to see if it's already in the database... And maybe unsafe too ?

How can i achieve such a system ?

Comment: For Facebook you can find the answer at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/faq#faq_104376946653191

Comment: @WizKid this seems to be only for games developped for Facebook, am i wrong ?

Comment: No it explains your options if you are not a game too